# How to use the let clause in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

The code below works perfectly in LINQPad, but when I implement it in Visual Studio it doesn't pull out any data. When I comment the `let` clause, and the cycles (1 to 5), I get the all the other data (Pin ...Notes). Can someone let me know how to implement the let clause in C#?

```
public List<RouteStatus> Route_AB_List(int yardId, int siteTypeId)
{
    using (var context = new COESystemContext())
    {
        var RouteList = from site in context.Sites
                           where site.YardID == yardId && site.SiteTypeID == siteTypeId && site.Season.SeasonYear == DateTime.Now.Year
                           orderby site.Community.Name ascending
                           let Cycles = site.JobCards
                                               .Where(job => job.OperationID == 1)
                                               .OrderByDescending(job => job.ClosedDate.HasValue)
                                               .ThenBy(job => job.ClosedDate)
                                               .Select(job => new { Date = job.ClosedDate })
                           select new RouteStatus
                           {
                               Pin = site.Pin,
                               Community = site.Community.Name,
                               Neighbourhood = site.Neighbourhood,
                               Address = site.StreetAddress,
                               Area = site.Area,
                               Notes = site.Notes,
                               Cycle1 = Cycles.FirstOrDefault().Date,
                               Cycle2 = Cycles.FirstOrDefault().Equals(null) ? (DateTime?)null : Cycles.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault().Date,
                               Cycle3 = Cycles.Skip(2).FirstOrDefault().Equals(null) ? (DateTime?)null : Cycles.Skip(2).FirstOrDefault().Date,
                               Cycle4 = Cycles.Skip(3).FirstOrDefault().Equals(null) ? (DateTime?)null : Cycles.Skip(3).FirstOrDefault().Date,
                               Cycle5 = Cycles.Skip(4).FirstOrDefault().Equals(null) ? (DateTime?)null : Cycles.Skip(4).FirstOrDefault().Date
                           };
        return RouteList.ToList();

    }
}
```

Comment: So the question is not about how to use the `let` clause. It's not clear what you mean by "in Linq" and "in VisualStudio". What matters is which database you connect to in both cases and which ORM executes the statement.

Comment: Sorry I meant in LinqPad, the code runs perfectly but when I implement it in VisualStudio it returns no data

Comment: @J.RaoulFEZE - Then edit your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that you do the select-where-order your cycles once for every Cycle1 to Cycle5.

Besides you have to have do something difficult if the result of FirstOrDefault is null.

My advice would be to use more Selects to optimize your code.

In smaller steps:

```
var selectedSitesAndCycles = dbContext.Sites

    // keep only those sites that ...
    .Where(site => site.YardID == yardId
                && site.SiteTypeID == siteTypeId
                && site.Season.SeasonYear == DateTime.Now.Year)

    // order the remaining sites in ascending order by name
    .OrderBy(site => site.Community.Name)

    // from every ordered site, get some properties and a list of 5 cycles:
    .Select(site => new
    {
        Pin = site.Pin,
        Community = site.Community.Name,
        Neighbourhood = site.Neighbourhood,
        Address = site.StreetAddress,
        Area = site.Area,
        Notes = site.Notes,

        ClosedDates = site.JobCards
            .Where(job => job.OperationID == 1)
            .OrderByDescending(job => job.ClosedDate.HasValue)
            .ThenBy(job => job.ClosedDate)
            .Select(job => Date = job.ClosedDate)
            .Take(5)
            .ToList(),
    });
```

Note the the query is not executed yet. I only take 5 cycles. I didn't use the keyword new when selecting the ClosedDate. Therefore CycleClosedDates is a `List<DateTime?>`.

In other words: every element of CycleClosedDates is a nullable DateTime. If you take `FirstOrDefault`, you get either the first nullable DateTime, which might be a DateTime or null, or you get a (DateTime?)null if there are not enough CycleClosedDates.

Let's examine the case where a site has only three JobCards:

```
JobCard[0] is closed and has ClosedDate 2020-03-10
JobCard[1] is not closed yet. ClosedDate isn (DateTime?)null
JobCard[3] is closed and has ClosedDate 2020-03-20
// There is no JobCard[4] [5]
```

The result is a `List<DateTime?>`, of length 3, where element [1] has no value. The result of `Skip(1).FirstOrDefault()` will be a nullable DateTime without value.

The nice thing is that `Skip(4).FirstOrDefault()` will also be a nullable DateTime without value, even though there are not 5 JobCards

Let's continue with an extra Select to create your five properties:

```
    .Select(site => new
    {
        Pin = site.Pin,
        Community = site.Community.Name,
        Neighbourhood = site.Neighbourhood,
        Address = site.StreetAddress,
        Area = site.Area,
        Notes = site.Notes,

        Cycle1 = site.CycleClosedDates.FirstOrDefault(),
        Cycle2 = site.CycleClosedDates.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault(),
        Cycle3 = site.CycleClosedDates.Skip(2).FirstOrDefault(),
        ...
    })
```

Note that the CycleClosedDates will be ordered only once. Because CycleClosedDates is already a `List<DateTime?>` it seems a bit superfluous to create separate properties instead of one list with length five. Consider in your second select

```
.Select(site => new
{
    Pin = site.Pin,
    Community = site.Community.Name,
    ...

    CycleClosedDates = new List[]
    {
        site.CycleClosedDates.FirstOrDefault(),
        site.CycleClosedDates.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault(),
        site.CycleClosedDates.Skip(2).FirstOrDefault(),
        ...
    },
};
```

Or after the first select:

```
// move the selected data to local process
.AsEnumerable()
// 2nd select:
    .Select(site => new
{
    Pin = site.Pin,
    Community = site.Community.Name,
    ...

    CycleClosedDates = site.CycleClosedDates
        .Concat(Enumerable.Repeat( (DateTime?)null, 5)
        .Take(5)
        .ToList();
```

This way you are certain that your CycleClosedDates has exactly five nullable DateTimes, even if there were no JobCards at all.

Comment: Thanks let me give it a try

Comment: Hello Herald. Thanks for your help. the code you provided works. I still try to wrap my head around the code to '''// move the selected data to local process'''.  Thanks a lot

Comment: AsEnumerable is only needed if another process, like a database management system is executing your query and you want to use your own methods. AsEnumerable will execute the query in a smart way (usually: don't fetch all data at once, but "per page as needed"). After AsEnumerable you can use local methods and the Enumerable LINQ methods that are not supported by IQueryable, like  Enumerable.Repeat. Disadvantage: a DBMS is much more optimized to do joining, sorting, selecting etc than your program. Let the DBMS do as much as possible = use AsEnumerable as late as possible.

Comment: Thanks you Harald for the insight. I really appreciate it.